# Japan re-entry with a tourist visa

Tags: customs-and-immigration, japan, visa-free-entry, polish-citizens

I'm planning a 14-day visit to Japan, during which time I would like to fly to South Korea for a side trip (some 4 days).

Will I experience any problems trying to re-enter Japan, few days before flying back to UK?

All within the 90-day period, due to the length of the trip... but is one not supposed to not return to Japan, for a period of time, after departing for the first time (to South Korea in my case)?

I hold a Polish/EU passport, but I suppose the same would apply to most countries.

Comment: Not sure why anyone would down-vote this question, without even providing some reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but is one not supposed to not return to Japan, for a period of time, after departing for the first time?

No, there is no such rule. If staying for 90 days and returning after a daytrip, they would be suspicious, of course, as it would look like you're living in Japan through visa runs, but not during such a short visit.

You will be good.

Comment: I seem to remember that during my last visit, while leaving Japan, I had to 'declare' I wouldn't go back within certain period, but maybe I'm making this up now! 
Your answer makes sense. Just thinking about the events like football World Cup in Japan and South Korea in 2002. Surely there would be fans going from one country to another.
I was just wondering if anyone here experienced anything of that sort.
As you say, I hope I will be good, especially if I have my itinerary at hand, to prove.

Answer (score 2):

By holding an Polish/EU passport, [you do not need a visa to enter Japan](http://www.mofa.go.jp/j_info/visit/visa/short/novisa.html) for short term visits - 90 days. The same applies to [visiting South Korea](http://nld.mofa.go.kr/english/eu/nld/visa/Free/index.jsp). So you should be fine.

Comment: I have been to Japan before, so am aware of this, but my question concentrated on the 're-entry' bit. Thanks anyway.